# c# does WaitForExit() go off, if the process is killed before endtime?

Tags: c#, file, process, wait, exit

The below should always run a program given at the file path pasted in. if waits for it to finish then re-runs. Does wait also go off if the program is killed?

```
    static void genp(string filepath)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filepath, "-n")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        genp(filepath);
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

`WaitForExit` waits infinite amount of time until the process is shut down by the operation system through a normal or abnormal termination.

The current thread is blocked until the associated process is terminated.

See also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) for further reference